# how to access values in shadowroot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lit-element, lit-html

I would like to know how to access value in shadowroot,

```
this.shadowRoot.getElementById("sending"); //not working

render() {
${this.value.map((e)=>{
<div class="form-check pb-2"  class="radio_send">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="sending" type="radio" id="sending" value="bank transfer" checked>
     <input class="form-check-input" name="sending" type="radio" id="sending" value="credit">
 </div>
});
}
```

Comment: You seem to be creating a lot of elements using the same id which is probably the reason using getElementById isn't working as you expect, what do you want to do? get the selected value in a radio group?

Comment: Also, where are you calling `this.shadowRoot.getElementById()`? It should be called in `firstUpdated()` (or later in the lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you call `this.shadowRoot` - before `firstUpdated` it might not hold anything, and even once it does `getElementById("sending")` will only return the first `bank transfer` radio button for the first entry in `this.value`.

Instead you want user actions to give you the value:

```js
render() {
    return html`${this.value.map(e => {
<div class="form-check pb-2 radio_send">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="sending" type="radio" value="bank transfer" checked
        @change=${this.setSendingState}>
    <input class="form-check-input" name="sending" type="radio" value="credit"
        @change=${this.setSendingState}>
</div>})`;
}

setSendingState(e) {
    this.sendingState = event.target.value;
}
```